# Does 舐めんじゃねぇぞ mean don’t fuck with me?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I know that なめんじゃねよ means don’t fuck with me but does 舐めんじゃねぇぞ have the same meaning or not ? if not what is the real meaning of the sentence 舐めんじゃねぇぞ?

Comment: The first one should also be じゃねえ (or, with small ぇ)

Answer (score 4):

The only difference (other than the kanji being used in the latter) is the particle ぞ, which can be seen as a "stronger よ", so yes, meaning-wise they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's yet just another variation of 舐めるなよ / なめんなよ